# Combing rows together/Summing up the data in an attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes

There are approximately +1,000 rows, almost all of them have the same name but are split up with different lengths.  I was looking for a way to combine the rows based on length and combine the names to a single name. So looking for a single row that keeps the name but has a total length.
I have tried the dissolve function but I don't think that was working considering it was copying the lengths when setting it to SUM.

I do believe it is a standard license that is version 10.5.
[image]

Looking for these to be all one attribute in a shapefile
[image]

Comment: There are many ways to do this with such a small table. What have you tried? Please [edit] the question to specify the version and license level of ArcGIS in use and to use the image helper correctly to include your image inline with the Question. It

Comment: I did update the post, fairly certain its a standard license but the version is 10.5. I have tried the dissolve function but that just duplicated the lengths field.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Dissolve**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool is definitely the way to go here. The reason it isn't calculating the total length is because your data is in a shapefile. You must either load your data into a file geodatabase, or calculate the length manually.

One way to do this is by using the **[Calculate Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm)** tool or [**field calculator**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C9E46547D3B246C1B89A36B0C84F7BA8). Of course, you'll need to ensure that your data is in a projected coordinate system, not a geographic coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the column header for NAME. Select [Summarize](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/tables/summarizing-data-in-a-table.htm). In the resulting dialogue box, expand the options for your length field.  If the length field is numeric, you can select "sum" and click OK.

Comment: It is a shapefile that I am using, I edited the post with another picture.  So this is really close to what I want, however, is there a way to make it as a shapefile layer.  The picture kind of shows what I mean, I want them combined to a single attribute that can be selected.

Comment: Shapefiles don't automatically update a field for feature geometry lengths like feature classes do.  So you'll have to calculate it yourself.  Add a  field to the shapefile (specify "DOUBLE" type), call it something like "length_m" for meters or "length_ft" for feet.  then right click that field heading and select "calculate geometry" and let it rip.